# Enqueue never runs

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

My enqueue scripts are never called I can't figure out why. All my paths are correct and I'm assuming the code is correct

**Functions.php**

```
function tim_enqueue_default_scripts() {
    if (ENVIRONMENT == 'dev') {
        $globaljs = 'global.js';
        $globalcss = 'global.css';
    }
    else {
        $globaljs = 'global-0.3.min.js';
        $globalcss = 'global-0.5.min.css';
    }
    wp_enqueue_script('globaljs', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/res/js/' . $globaljs . '', false, false, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('globalcss', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/res/css/' . $globalcss . '', false, false, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tim_enqueue_default_scripts');
```

**Header.php**

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

**Footer.php**

```
<?php wp_footer();  ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )` instead of [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) (or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) if this is a child  theme)?

Comment: Your code works for me though you are getting `media="1"` with the stylesheet, which could be causing an issue. Other than the issues pointed out by @PatJ and that issues with `media` the problem is not with the code posted.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure about the parameters wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script uses.(The parameters are not same for both )

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

you are giving false,false,true for dependency,version and media which is a blunder mistake.If you are not sure about them, you can avoid them and if you want to following is an example

```
wp_register_style( 'custom-style', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.css', 
    array(), 'version1', 'all' );
```

and in wp_enqueue_script you need to change $deps(dependency) parameter to `array()` instead of `false`

Answer (score 0):

Try `wp_register_script()` and `wp_register_style()` first
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Something like (for the style at least):

```
wp_register_style('my_style_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/css/my_styles.css');
wp_enqueue_style('my_style_css');
```

Comment: The `wp_register_` functions are optional, convenient sometimes, but optional. And the code works for me.